# Inequality in Normed Space (similar to the form in Clarkson Inequality)

Tags: normed-spaces

In a normed space $(X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$, let $0<p<+\infty$, and $(x,x')_p:=(\Vert x\Vert^p+\Vert x'\Vert^p)^{1\over p}$.  I want to prove that there exists positive numbers $c_i$ so that $c_1(x,x')_p\leqslant (x+x',x-x')_p\leqslant c_2(x,x')_p$.

I noticed that if I find a positive number $c_2$, I can omit the proof of the existence of $c_1$, and vice versa. So I decided to only prove the existence of $c_2$.

I found in http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:999104/FULLTEXT01.pdf (Page 21, Proposition 2.4) that there is a proven inequality in $\mathbb{C}$, but the proof relies on the parallelogram law which may not hold in a general normed space.

I still wonder how to prove the existence of $c_2$ in a general normed space (not necessarily inner product spaces). Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1 \leq p<\infty$ we can do the following: $(x+x',x-x')_p^{p} =\|x+x'\|^{p}+\|x-x'\|^{p}\leq 2(\|x\|+\|x'\|)^{p}$ and $(\|x\|+\|x'\|)^{p}=2^{p} (\frac {\|x\|+\|x'\|} 2)^{p}\leq 2^{p}\frac { (\|x\|^{p}+\|x'\|^{p}) } 2$ because the function $t \to t^{p}$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$. So we can take $c_2=2^{(p-1)/p}$.

For $0<p<1$ replace convexity argument by the simple fact $(a+b)^{p} \leq 2^{p}(a^{p}+b^{p})$. [Writing $c$ for $\max \{a,b\}$ we have $(a+b)^{p}\leq (c+c)^{p}=2^{p}c^{p}\leq 2^{p}(a^{p}+b^{p})$].

Comment: Thanks! But is $t\mapsto t^p$ still convex for $p\in (0,1)$? And $c_2$ might be just $2$ in your answer.

Comment: @MaxYoung I have edited.